# Server Error (500) on Django 1.6

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have Django 1.6 project and is run using the Gunicorn web application server behind the Nginx web server. Now i want to transfer that project to new host. For that i have copied all code across the new machine and install all required dependencies using pip install -r requirements.txt that went successful.

When i was trying to run `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` it was giving me below error:

```
Unable to process log entry: Unsupported Sentry DSN scheme:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/forttottensquare/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/raven/contrib/django/models.py", line 174, in sentry_exception_handler
    client.captureException(exc_info=sys.exc_info(), request=request)
  File "/var/www/html/forttottensquare/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/raven/contrib/django/models.py", line 54, in <lambda>
    _getattr_ = lambda x, o: getattr(get_client(), o)
  File "/var/www/html/forttottensquare/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/raven/contrib/django/models.py", line 154, in get_client
    instance = Client(**options)
  File "/var/www/html/forttottensquare/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/raven/base.py", line 141, in _init_
    self.set_dsn(dsn, transport)
  File "/var/www/html/forttottensquare/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/raven/base.py", line 195, in set_dsn
    transport_registry=self._registry,
  File "/var/www/html/forttottensquare/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/raven/conf/remote.py", line 69, in from_string
    raise InvalidDsn(ERR_UNKNOWN_SCHEME.format(url.scheme))
InvalidDsn: Unsupported Sentry DSN scheme:
```

I had a below settings in settings.py file:

```
RAVEN_CONFIG = {
    'dsn': os.environ.get('SENTRY_DSN', ''),
}
```

I had tried to change it with

```
RAVEN_CONFIG = {
    'dsn': None
}
```

Or

```
RAVEN_CONFIG = {}
```

After that it gives me below error on console:

> Raven is not configured (logging is disabled). Please see the documentation for more information.

And in browser it gives me just Server Error (500).

SO what should i do to fix that issue?

Comment: You have to pass the dsn for Sentry to initialize. Passing `None` will not work. Also check  `os.environ.get('SENTRY_DSN', '')` - the environment property might not be set.

Comment: it seems a problem on how you have specify the DNS what's inside teh `SENTRY_DNS` string?

PS:a littel bit OT, but django 1.6 was supported till 1/4/2015 .. which is a long time ago.

Comment: Ok, how did i found the value needed to set dsn? I have no idea about it.

Comment: DSN is an account related information. Check this - https://docs.sentry.io/quickstart/

Comment: Is there a way to fetch that from existing project?

Comment: Thanks, it got resolved after creating the account on https://sentry.io/ and i have used that dsn key.